# Is there a way to automatically run some checks when GitHub pull requests are created?

Tags: .net, github, coding-style

I am looking for automatically doing checks like:

- Copyright header comments
- Coding guidelines
- Checking references for old libraries (I'll use this on .NET..)
- something else..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [declare on your GitHub repo a **webhook**](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/creating/) which would respond to a [`pull_request` event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestevent).

You need a server listening for the json payload sent by that webhook, but from there the listener can pull the PR branch, and perform any test you need.

Another approach is [enabling status check](https://help.github.com/articles/about-required-status-checks/), with [status checks](https://help.github.com/articles/about-status-checks/) being based on external processes, such as continuous integration builds, which run for each push you make to a repository. You can see the pending, passing, or failing state of status checks next to individual commits in your pull request.

If status checks are required for a repository, the required status checks must pass before you can merge your branch into the protected branch.